# Ideals of $\Bbb{Z}_{p^n}$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Suppose $p$ is a prime. Prove that for each natural number $n$, the ideals of $\Bbb{Z}_{p^n}$ form a chain and that each proper ideal is nilpotent. Then show that the product $R={\prod}_{n>1}\Bbb{Z}_{p^n}$ has a nil ideal that is not nilpotent.

Comment: I have no idea about it. I even don't know the structure of the ideals of $Z_{p^n}$ .Who can help me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: the collection of ideals of $R/I$ is in bijection with the collection of ideals of $R$ which contain $I$. What are the ideals of $\mathbf Z$ containing $p^n\mathbf Z$?

Comment: @马紫菜 What is $\mathbf Z_{p^n}$?

Comment: I'm sorry, My question is about $\Bbb{Z}_{p^n}$.

Comment: @马紫菜 What is it?

Comment: @ Bruno Joyal It's modulo $p^n$ residual rings

Comment: @马紫菜 Ok. That is usually written $\mathbf Z/p^n\mathbf Z$, which is why I had modified your question.

Comment: @ Bruno Joyal But we use $\Bbb{Z}_{p^n}$ most, at least it's so in my book.

Comment: @ Bruno Joyal Thank you for your hint, I understand more about it now. I will have my class latter, see you.

Comment: @马紫菜 My pleasure. Don't forget to accept the answer if you are satisfied with it!